# PC IP address through internet to ping VPN host

Tags: cisco-asa, vpn, firewall

I have made a network and i posted the topology below, i need to ping through the internet to a host inside the network. which will essentially be a VPN and i need help on giving the network "VPN" properties and to make it a VPN and making a tunnel to my PC's ip address, how can i do that?
I have to get through the firewall as well to get it to ping a host on the inside

[image]

Comment: A VPN can be from the host to the other host, from your firewall to a remote host, or from your firewall to a remote firewall. You don't VPN from a host on your network to the firewall on your network. If you configure a VPN on your firewall, you need to have some software on the remote host which can connect to the VPN on your firewall.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

For ping you need to allow ICMP Type: 0, 8 thru ASA
Depend of technology used for VPN it could be 500/UDP, 4500/UDP, 5000/UDP, ESP[50], 443/TCP, 1723/GRE[47]

If inside host if based on RFC1918 and need to be accesible from internet than you need add NAT statment as well.

Answer (score 1):

Cisco has some really nice documents with configuration examples and step by step guide.
E.g. this one seems to fit your scenario well:
http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/anyconnect-secure-mobility-client/119006-configure-anyconnect-00.html

It goes through the steps of configuring all that is needed on the ASA, including the Anyconnect package that gets downloaded to the "pc on the internet".

Note that it also mentions that you may need an additional license on the ASA.